# What package should I install to work with OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, static-linking, pacman-package-manager

I want to use `pacman` to install `OpenGL` but I get an error compiling.

I want to link with `-lglut` `-lGLU` `-lGL` but what packages are those? Is there a way to find out?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <SDL2\SDL.h>
#include <GL\glu.h>

int main(int arc, char *argv[]) {
    cout << "Hello world" << endl;
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    return 0;
}
```

I run (obviously I get an error saying the lib is not found if using `-lGLU`)

```
g++ *.cpp
```

This is the error

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ccztMdnY.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x39): undefined reference to `__imp_glShadeModel'
F:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o): In function `main':
C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt0_c.c:18: undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: add `-lopengl32`

Comment: @Rabbid76 That was easy :D. So what did I do? Using Windows OpenGL? I want to link statically if possible

Comment: Yes. The instruction set is limited (I think to OpenGL 2.0). You've to use [Glad](https://glad.dav1d.de/) or [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) for full OpenGL instructions.

Comment: @Asken: You can't link OpenGL statically, because it's a system API, which interface library require updates. OpenGL itself is not **a** library, it's an API specification. The actual implementation is part of the graphics driver.

Comment: @datenwolf Super thanks. Got it.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I'll check out glew and go from there. Thanks

Comment: Seems like I should run `g++ *.cpp -lopengl32 -lglew32 -lglu32`